# ¿Como puedo cerrar una pregunta duplicada que no ha sido respondida aún?

Tags: discusión

Me he topado un caso algo curioso.

Un usuario nuevo en el sitio ha hecho dos veces la misma pregunta cambiando un poco el enunciado en cada una. El código que muestra es diferente cada vez pero si se lee bien se puede ver que es el mismo código y el mismo problema.

Las preguntas son estas

[Error: [ng:areq] Angular chart js](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20213/error-ngareq-angular-chart-js)

[Graficos de angular chart js](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20253/graficos-de-angular-chart-js)

Comenté en una de ellas buscando información y luego intenté cerrar la otra ya que lo más probable es que el usuario esté intentando obtener respuesta posteandola varias veces lo cual no sigue el modelo del sitio

https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers

Al intentarlo me ha dado el siguiente error

[image: error]

¿Que se puede hacer ante esos casos?

¿Debo pedirle al propio autor que la cierre o la debo cerrar por otra causa?

Comment: Relacionadas: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165928/we-should-be-able-to-close-questions-as-duplicates-of-any-question y http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256054/this-question-does-not-have-an-upvoted-or-accepted-answer

Comment: Bueno, este caso es especial, usa el mismo nombre de usuario pero son dos cuentas diferentes (asumiendo que es la misma persona). En un caso mas general, donde son dos personas diferentes, me parece mejor no tener en cuenta la fecha de la pregunta sino cual de ellas esta mejor planteada y/o muestra un mayor esfuerzo de investigación y /o comprensión del problema puntual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alguna vez converse eso con @LuiggiMendoza, lo mejor que se puede hacer en esos casos es reportarla como: **se necesita la intervención de un moderador**, y detallar los motivos del reporte, así el moderador la revisa y la cierra inmediatamente.

Comment: .. o las une (*merge*)

Comment: Así es.........